# AJAX: Why does $_REQUEST on server side not contain the variable passed from JS in URL by GET method?

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have three `div`s saved in an `array` as `simple_html_dom` objects. I needed to change a CSS property of two of them on the click of a button. That's easy, but then *I also need to make that change in the CSS property (in the simple_html_dom object stored in the aforementioned array) in the PHP script on the server side.*

So I figured from my web search I needed **AJAX** for this. So I read up [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp), and I am following [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_suggest), and doing something like:

**On the client side:**

```
function xyz(var divIdOne, var divIdTwo) {
    document.getElementById(params.divIdOne).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(params.divIdTwo).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById(params.divIdTwo).style.border = "5px solid red";

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
    else { xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","myfile.php?pass_back="+"pass_back",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**On server side:**

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $requestkey => $requestvalue) {
    echo $requestkey.': '.$requestvalue;
}
if (array_key_exists('pass_back', $_REQUEST)) {
    foreach ($array_of_divs as $div) {
        if ($div->id=$divIdOne) {
            $div->style='display:none';
        } else if ($div->id=$divIdTwo) {
            $div->style='display:block';
        }
    }
} else {echo 'FALSE!';}
```

The first `foreach loop` prints other variables but does not print `pass_back`. The next `if` block does not execute at all. The `else` block executes. This means that `$_REQUEST` clearly does not contain pass_back. Can anyone pinpoint why, or what I did wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you use $_GET instead of $_REQUEST?

Comment: @MarceloRibeiro Nope!

Comment: Have you tried to go to the url directly in the browser, just to make sure it is not the ajax call? i.e. accessing /myfile.php?pass_back=pass_back directly? How are you checking what the php script is printing?

Comment: It seems you're sending an `async` request but i don't see how you verify that your `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` are _not working_. You either need to set `false` and return a `.responseText` for this or play with `.readyState` to verify the return.

Comment: @vlzvl By seeing that on the server side, the `foreach` does not print any `pass_back`, and  in the `if-else` conditional expression, the `else` part is executed, i.e. "FALSE!" is echoed.

Comment: @MarceloRibeiro `$_REQUEST` already has values `attempt=3` and `page=5`. Now, when I try the URL `myfile.php?attempt=3&page=5&pass_back=pass_back#`, it prints the three variables (for the `foreach` loop), and does not print `FALSE!` But I do not know what to conclude from this?

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see the error. How do you check that you're not sending the data properly? I suggest using this piece of code in order to check what your server is receiving from your request:

```
function xyz() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);// Let's see what the server is echoing
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","myfile.php?pass_back="+"pass_back",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Please, let us know the output.

Comment: I used `alert()` instead of `console.log()`. It did not alert anything, and there was no change.

Comment: Nothing at all? That's funny. Does print_r($_GET) send out anything at all? Could you write that sentence before the first foreach and tell us what the alert says? Thanks.

Comment: @arconmon [I wrote an SSCCE here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981040/ajax-how-to-change-a-value-on-client-side-as-well-as-server-side-on-button-clic) , you can see it, this will help understand the question better.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use jquery and firebug, and first get rid of the following problem: why is passback variable not received.

Create the file: test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <title>Html page</title>
</head>

<body>


<script>
    (function($){

        $.post("myfile.php", {
            passback: "pooo"
        }, function(d){
            console.log(d);
        });


    })(jQuery);

// or if you cannot use jquery
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        // do something with the response, if you need it...
        // document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "myfile.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("passback=pooo");

// src:  http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Then create the file: myfile.php

```
<?php



if(isset($_REQUEST['passback'])){
    echo "ok";
}
else{
    echo "oops";
}
```

Next, download firefox, and download the firebug extension (or you can use chrome's console alternatively). The goal here is to see what is being passed through the network.

Launch test.php in a browser, open the firebug console (or chrome's console),
and debug until you see the "ok" message.

Comment: I can not use JQuery. That is the problem. I can use YUI library though, but not JQuery. Will be great if you can tell me a YUI or a JS only way.

Comment: Then you should try adding that restriction to your question to begin with. That's a pretty big caveat.