# How to change the value of an HTML element's attribute (on both client and server side) on the click of a button?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

**CONTEXT:-**

This question is about some basic concepts about AJAX. I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) and this example [for the JS part](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_suggest), and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp) (the last one on this page) [for the PHP part](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp).

So suppose the scenerio is that the JS is invoked on the click of a `button`. Now when the button is clicked and the JS function is invoked, the entire web page is already loaded. So if I pass a variable from JS in the `URL` passed from the `XMLHTTPRequest.open()` function (and using the `GET` method), the variable is sent to the `$_REQUEST` array on the server-side.

**1. Now since the page has already been loaded, so how can I make changes to, say the value of an element's attribute, while the element is already displayed.**

**SCENERIO:-**

I have a PHP `array` with `HTML` for three `div`'s, and they are echoed/displayed. Initially all the `div`s except the first one have a `display:none;` style property. Now on the *click of a button* in the first `div`, I want to call a `JS` function where I set `display:none` to the first `div`, and `display:block;` to the second `div`. Now that is easy. *But I want this change in the display property in the HTML for the respective div in the aforementioned array on the server side as well.*

So I figured I need `AJAX`. Following [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_suggest), I tried sending a variable in URL, and then tried to get the variable from `$_REQUEST`, but `$_REQUEST` does not seem to contain it. Although I [asked this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962104/ajax-why-does-request-on-server-side-not-contain-the-variable-passed-from-js), but I feel it might be because the part of the page where I am writing the code to get the variable from `$_REQUEST` is already executed, I am wondering where should I write the code to execute only after the click of the mentioned button?

**2. Basically where do we write the AJAX script since the code for the page is already executed?**

NOTE:- Don't suggest JQuery. I can't use JQuery, I can use YUI though. I searched SO and found solutions using some JQuery method.

---

**JS CODE:-**

```
function xyz(var divIdOne, var divIdTwo) {
    document.getElementById(params.divIdOne).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(params.divIdTwo).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById(params.divIdTwo).style.border = "5px solid red";

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
    else { xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","myfile.php?pass_back="+"pass_back",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Where in the server side PHP script do I write the code which receives the variable from the URL so that it is executed after the button is clicked (the button whose click event invoked this JS fucntion).

I was trying to do something like this at a random place in the server file but it does not work out:

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $requestkey => $requestvalue) { //loop for just checking the elements of $_REQUEST
    echo $requestkey.': '.$requestvalue;
}
if (array_key_exists('pass_back', $_REQUEST)) {
    foreach ($array_of_divs as $div) {
        if ($div->id=$divIdOne) {
            $div->style='display:none';
        } else if ($div->id=$divIdTwo) {
            $div->style='display:block';
        }
    }
} else {echo 'FALSE!';}
```

Comment: `request.onreadystatechange = function(){if(request.status === 200 and request.readyState === 4){var data = eval('('+request.responseText+')'}}`. Should use PHP's `echo json_encode($assocArray);` Sever Side. JavaScript `var data` would become JavaScript Object. `onreadystatechange` when those requirement are both true you deal with the DOM.

Comment: where are the codes pertaining to this question?

Comment: @Ghost I posted some code to [this linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962104/ajax-why-does-request-on-server-side-not-contain-the-variable-passed-from-js). The file it is a part of is huge, I just posted relevant bits. Moreover, I am not sure if I should post the code here as well as it will make the question too long.

Comment: @PHPglue `echo json_encode($assocArray)` What is `$assocArray` in here? I don't get this statement either: "`onreadystatechange` when those requirement are both true you deal with the DOM"?

Comment: @PHPglue no need to use eval in this case. `JSON.parse()` is enough

Comment: @PHPglue I did not do `request.onreadystatechange = function(){...}` part because I do not need any data on the server side after the $_REQUEST is received. I just need to change an element's attribute value on button click.

Comment: @Zarah if i understand correctly? you need to make changes on both client side `display: none;`, and in PHP `simple-html-dom $element->style = 'display: none'`? something like that? i suggest debug per piece, first manipulate the client side first, after thats done, then move on the PHP side (get that request variables working first),

Comment: @Ghost Yeah you got this right. I was successful in making the change on client side (as you can see in the JS code). I am stuck at doing this on server side. `$_REQUEST` does not seem to contain `pass_back`, so I am anticipating that I am not writing the AJAX script at the right place in the file, so that it can be run at the right time?

Comment: @Zarah just make sure check the browser console (`network tab`), from there, its easy to debug

Comment: The `XMLHttpRequest` sends data to the Server (your PHP page), usually when some Event occurs. That data is processed on your PHP page, with the `$_GET` Superglobal Array in your case. When you handle your stuff on the PHP page, you send the data back to JavaScript, usually as a JSON encoded String. In PHP `json_encode()` takes an Associative Array as it's argument. `onreadystatechage` happens when the `request.readyState` changes. `4` is ready, complete, and delivered. If `request.status === 200 request.readyState === 4` the data that is `echo`ed or `print`ed in your PHP page is processed.

Comment: and by the way `,"myfile.php?pass_back="+"pass_back"` this doesn't make sense, why are you concatenating `pass_back`, should write the whole string instead, or i guess `pass_back` in a variable?

Comment: @Ghost "should write the whole string instead" which string? You can see the PHP script I posted, I am just using it to check if it exists in `$_REQUEST` (which means the button has been clicked and now is the time to change the display property values), and if it does, I change the display property values.

Comment: @PHPglue Thank you, the last line in what you wrote - I do not want any data to be printed, I just need to change the style property values of an already printed div.

Comment: @Zarah i don't see anymore reason for this not to work, my only take here is maybe the php url is not correct.

Comment: @Ghost Just one last thing: it is the URL from which the JS function was called, it's OK to use this URL, I do not need a separate file for AJAX script right? And I am also using an absolute URL here just to be sure.

Comment: @Zarah so all of this is on a same file? well i suggest request it on another php file, just make sure you have the correct url

Comment: The PHP that builds your page originally has nothing to do with the page that should be in your `request.open('GET', 'here.php')`.

Comment: @PHPglue These are the same file. The PHP that builds the page has the html for the element whose style property I want to change. So I have to process the request in the same file which builds my page. The URL is to the same file.

Comment: Do your PHP that processes the AJAX request on a different page. The JavaScript stays on the page you want to affect your HTML on. Read the notes in my Answer. Take your time and pay attention to my example.

Comment: @PHPglue I can not do that because the HTML whose style property I want to change is in this file. That's the problem. I wrote an SSCCE, but nobody is answering it. You can find it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981040/ajax-how-to-change-a-value-on-client-side-as-well-as-server-side-on-button-clic)

Comment: That doesn't matter. You can still use a separate PHP file. You just don't get AJAX yet. That is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if i understand correctly:

You set the display property on some div with js.
You want to update some flag on your server so next time a request is made you get the same display properties as the client.

AJAX is asynchronous, so you can call it wherever you want (your button click, document ready, etc).

Make an AJAX request to some url in server that can answer it and update your flags with the values you want. You may need some kind of persistence to keep those for the next time you reload your page or you won't notice any change.

Make sure you understand what [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is.

Comment: I read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) entire tutorial for this, but there is something I am probably not getting right. I understand AJAX is Asynchronous, but does this mean I can right the code to read `$_REQUEST` anywhere in my PHP code, and it will be read after the JS function (invoked on button click) is executed, so that it contains the variable sent to it from the JS function?

Comment: Once you type an URL in your browser and press enter a request is sent to the server, it processes anything you may get in the $_REQUEST and then sends back to the client html code (including javascripts and css ofc).
If you make an AJAX request you may be treating the data correctly but you are not doing anything with the answer. If you want to see what the server is sending back try printing the value of the responseText. 
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

Comment: Hi, I wrote a [self-contained example for this problem and posted it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981040/ajax-how-to-change-a-value-on-client-side-as-well-as-server-side-on-button-clic), this makes my question more clear. May be you can suggest a solution there?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of an AJAX function:

```
function ajax(url, method, send, success){
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest || new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'), ec = [], s, sl;
  if(send){
    for(var i in send){
      ec.push(encodeURIComponent(i)+'='+encodeURIComponent(send[i]));
    }
    s = ec.join('&').replace(/%20/g, '+'); sl = s.length;
  }
  else{
    s = null; sl = 0;
  }
  if(method.match(/^get$/i)){
    s = s === null ? '' : '?'+s;
    x.open('GET', url+s); x.send();
  }
  else{
    x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    x.setRequestHeader('Content-length', sl);
    x.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');
    x.open('POST', url); x.send(s);
  }
  if(success){
    x.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(x.readyState === 4 && x.status === 200){
        /* when PHP has processed what you send through `.send()` or a $_GET URL
          your function will fire with the evaluated responseText passed to it
        */
        success(eval('('+x.responseText+')'));
      }
    }
  }
}
ajax('page.php', 'GET', {property:'value', property2:'value2'}, function(data){
  /* when PHP has processed what you send through `.send()` or a $_GET URL
    the anonymous function here executes sending what should be JSON
    (if you `echo json_encode($associativeArrayYouMake);`on your PHP page)
    through the data argument here - so data is JSON containing your PHP
    Associative Array properties
  */
  // affect the DOM
  // document.getElementById('someId').innerHTML = data.some_property;
  // or document.getElementById('someId').innerHTML = data['some_property'];
});
```

Comment: What do I do with this more complicated example? I already pointed to a simpler example in the question in the first line.

Comment: I posted an SSCCE [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981040/ajax-how-to-change-a-value-on-client-side-as-well-as-server-side-on-button-clic). Can you please look at it and suggest something?