# AJAX: How to change a value on client side as well as server side on button click?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

In the following SSCCE,

1. I have a string which contains the HTML for three `div`s.
2. I add a `style="display:none;"` attribute to all the `div`s except the first one.
3. I add a button to all the `div`s except the last one, and add a JS `onclick` event listener, which should change the current `div`'s style property to `style="display:none;"` (current `div`'s `id` attribute passed to the JS function.) and the next `div`'s (it's `id` is also passed to the JS function) style property to `style="display:block;"`
4. I add a `submit` button to the last `div` which submits the `form`. I did not write the `action` attribute of the `form` or any event listener for this button because that's not the concern right now.
5. I print the div's.

### PROBLEM:

The `currentId` and the `nextId` passed to the JS event listener of the button click event are calculated in a function named `returnCurrentId` which takes the  `$array_of_divs` and `$array_of_ids` as arguments. Then it checks which `div` had `style="display:none;"` and sets it as the `current_id`. Then the id next to it in the `$array_of_ids` becomes the `next_id`.

The problem arises when the JS changes the style property of the `div`s whose `id`s have been passed to it on the client side, and nothing changes on the server side. So on the server side, it is the same `$array_of_ids` being passed to `returnCurrentId` without any changes in the display properties, and so the same `id`s of the first and second `div` are returned. They are passed to JS, and then again the same `div` is displayed again.

### MY EFFORT:

So I have been reading up on AJAX here, and I tried to send a variable named `pass_back` in the `URL` of `XMLHTTPRequest.open(GET, URL, TRUE)`, and on the server side, tried to check if $_REQUEST contains it, and when it does, I make the same change to the style properties, but it does not seem to contain it.

## QUESTION:

I anticipate I am placing the block of code on the wrong place, but then where do I put it.

So can anyone give me some tips/suggestion/solution?

```
<?php
echo '<html><head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <script>
        function clickButton(currentId, nextId) {
            alert(currentId+","+nextId); //check
            
            document.getElementById(currentId).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById(nextId).style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById(nextId).style.border = "5px solid red";//check
            
            //**************************
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
            else { xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","C:/xampp/htdocs/testing.php?pass_back="+"pass_back",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            //**************************
    
        }
    </script>
</head><body>';


//String of all the div's
$haystack = '<div id="div1" style="width:500px; height:250px; background-color:#fd77ba">Div1</div>
<div id="div2" style="width:500px; height:250px; background-color:#7781fd">Div2</div>
<div id="div3" style="width:500px; height:250px; background-color:#77fd9b">Div3</div>';

//Adding divs as DOM objects to an array
require 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\simple_html_dom.php';
$html = str_get_html($haystack);
foreach ($html->find('div') as $div) {
    $array_of_divs[] = $div;
}

//Extract id attributes from all elements of $array_of_divs and add to $array_of_ids
foreach ($array_of_divs as $div) {
    $array_of_ids[] = $div->id;
}

//Add style="display:none;" property to all divs except the first one
for ($i=1; $i<count($array_of_divs); $i++) {
    $array_of_divs[$i]->style = 'display:none;';
}

//Strings of the pseudo button to navigate to the next div on the same page and real button to navigate to another page
$pseudo_btn = '<button type="button" onClick="clickButton(\''.returnCurrentId($array_of_divs, $array_of_ids)['current_id'].'\',\''.returnCurrentId($array_of_divs, $array_of_ids)['next_id'].'\')" style="font-family:Oxygen,sans-serif; font-style: normal;font-variant: normal;font-weight: normal;font-size: 99%;line-height: normal;font-size-adjust: none;font-stretch: normal; background-color: #494f50; color: #ffffff; padding-top: 5px;padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 10px;margin-top: 50px;margin-right: 10px;margin-bottom: 50px;margin-left: 10px; text-decoration:none;">Submit</button>';
$real_btn = '<span style="background-color:red;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="font-family:Oxygen,sans-serif; font-style: normal;font-variant: normal;font-weight: normal;font-size: 99%;line-height: normal;font-size-adjust: none;font-stretch: normal; background-color: #494f50; color: #ffffff; padding-top: 5px;padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 10px;margin-top: 50px;margin-right: 10px;margin-bottom: 50px;margin-left: 10px; text-decoration:none;"></span>';

//Add $pseudo-btn to all except last div on this page, add $real_btn to the last div
$last_id = end($array_of_ids);
for ($j=0; $j<count($array_of_ids); $j++) {
    if ($array_of_ids[$j] !== $last_id ) {
        $array_of_divs[$j]->innertext .= $pseudo_btn;
    } else {
        $array_of_divs[$j]->innertext .= $real_btn;
    }
}

//Print all the divs
echo '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">';
foreach ($array_of_divs as $div) { echo $div; }
echo '</form>';

//**********************************************
//IF $_REQUEST CONTAINS pass_back (i.e. THE BUTTON HAS BEEN PRESSED, CHANGE DISPLAY PREPERTY OF CURRENT AND NEXT DIV
if (array_key_exists('pass_back',$_REQUEST)) {
        foreach ($array_of_divs as $divs_el) {
            if ( $divs_el->id == returnCurrentId($array_of_divs, $array_of_ids)[current_id] ) {
                $divs_el->style = 'display:none;';
            } else if ( $divs_el->id == returnCurrentId($array_of_divs, $array_of_ids)[next_id] ) {
                $divs_el->style = 'display:block;'; 
            }
        }
} else {
    echo '$_REQUEST does not contain pass_back';
}
//***********************************************

//This function returns the id of the current div which is displayed.
function returnCurrentId($array_of_divs, $array_of_ids) {
    for ($c=0; $c<count($array_of_divs); $c++) {
        $style_value = $array_of_divs[$c]->style;
        $style_value = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $style_value);//This removes all kinds of white space.
        if (strpos($style_value,'display:none') === false) {
            $current_id= $array_of_divs[$c]->id;
            break;
        }
    }
    $current_position = array_search($current_id, $array_of_ids);
    $next_id = $array_of_ids[$current_position + 1];
    $array_to_pass= array('current_id'=>$current_id, 'next_id'=>$next_id);
    return $array_to_pass;
}



echo '</body></html>';
?>
```

Comment: This is a bad way to go about your project. You can use PHP to build your original HTML page, but unless you're getting information from your database, or you have a lot of repetitive code, just do your HTML and JavaScript separate. Your JavaScript should really be on an external page, so it's cached into Browser memory. If you have to walk the DOM on your own page, instead of using PHP use JavaScript. You can simply have an HTML class attribute, which you affect with CSS, instead of styling with HTML that's created with PHP. If you need to style when an Event occurs, then you use JavaScript.

Comment: For your use AJAX is used to send data to a, usually different, PHP page. You use `$_GET['property']` to get the `value` part of the $_GET url where it shows like: `?property=value&prop=val`. In other words, after `?` on the PHP page you assign with `xhr.open('GET', 'here.php?property=value&prop=val')`. You usually don't send HTML back to your JavaScript `onreadystatechang` upon `xhr.status === 200 && readyState === 4`. When responding with your PHP page, you usually store the information in a PHP Associative Array, which you `echo json_encode($arrayHere);`.

Comment: @PHPglue Firstly, thank you for taking time for this. Now the thing is I am working on Moodle. So everything is set up in there already, and in order to add a little functionality, I need to work the way Moodle works. So there is a page called `renderer.php` (its code is huge, so I wrote this example to show my problem) which contains all the code to generate the output. All the JS is in a file called `module.js` (I added it in one page for this example). And though Moodle has CSS in a file called `styles.css`, I can not edit it and I would like to override its styles, so I use inline CSS here

Comment: @PHPglue Now although I can make a separate file to receive the AJAX request (whose URL I will pass to the `XMLHTTPRequest.open` function), but how will I change the style attribute of a simple_html_dom object in the first PHP file from this new PHP file? Moreover, I need to change the style property on server side as well because the `returnCurrentId` function decides which one is the current div based on which `div` does not have `display:none;` as the value of `style` attribute. SO if this change is not made on the server side in this file, it will keep passing JS the `id`s of the

Comment: same first and second `div`s. And that keeps displaying the second `div`. How can I go about this problem?

Comment: @PHPglue _AJAX is used to send data to a, **usually** different, PHP page_ - this means it can be sent to the same page, may be unusually? I understand that the page is already loaded, but I wish there must be a way.

Comment: @zarah I think you should put a valid HTTP URL in this bit: xmlhttp.open("GET","C:/xampp/htdocs/testing.php?pass_back="+"pass_back",true); try using something like http://localhost/testing.php?pass_back=passback c:/ is not a valid protocol

Comment: `@Zarah`, it looks like you can add `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='yourCSS.css' />`, and you can probably put your CSS page in a folder, right? Then you should. You could send AJAX to the same page, but then you have to add a bunch of PHP code to your page to make sure the initial state and the AJAX states are different. In other words, add a bunch of PHP conditions so you don't get a JSON response with HTML code you already used to make the page. Finally, `C:/xampp/htdocs/testing.php` should probably be `localhost/testing.php`.

Comment: It's important to understand the following: When you put a URL into your Browser Address Bar, your Sever looks to see if it's PHP. If it is, it runs the PHP portion of the code before spiting it out to the Client. Some of this code may render HTML. Once the Client gets the code through a Browser, HTML runs. If there are `<script>` tags in the HTML, JavaScript runs anything it can. Since you don't always know what the Client will do next, you can create Events that will execute when the Event occurs.

Comment: AJAX should not be used to change PHP on the page that was created with the URL you put into your Browser Address Bar. If you did do that, you'd need to reprinting the HTML. HTML the Client can already see. You can just use another PHP page, which you set `xhr.open('GET', 'location.php')`. When information is sent to `location.php` with AJAX you just `echo` what you want to go back to your JavaScript `xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){if(xhr.status === 200 && xhr.readyState === 4){/* xhr.responseText */}}`. `xhr.responseText` holds the PHP String that is `echo`ed from `location.php`.

Comment: Once you get the information your want out of `xhr.responseText`, in the same place as the comment above, you use JavaScript to style what you need, or just `Element.className = 'whatever'`, and affect in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zarah, a couple of ideas that might help you:

As I said in my comment, try to change this bit:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","C:/xampp/htdocs/testing.php?pass_back="+"pass_back",true);
```

for something like:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","testing.php?pass_back="+"pass_back",true);
```

taking into consideration that that's a valid route to a file called testing.php in your web server. The url parameter of the open() method, must be an address to a file on a **server** and you must use a valid **URL** that points to that file.

Another idea. You can send post information using this approach:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","testing.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("passback=passback");
```

so you could try to send it using POST instead of GET to see what happens. It might throw some light into the matter.

More things.

It is possible that due to your php configuration, $_REQUEST doesn't contain anything whereas $_GET does. This could be a good reason to check $_GET instead of $_REQUEST. However, if you do want to use $_REQUEST, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701588/why-is-request-empty) you can find more info about the topic.

**EDIT**

The following code (based on yours) works for me (debian APACHE/php 5.4). I've put all the code on the same page. I don't like it very much but it's only to point out that it works. The AJAX part sends the data to main.php and main.php simply sends back what it receives. Then the AJAX part simply alerts the answer from the server.

**main.php**

```
<?php
//**********************************************
//IF $_REQUEST CONTAINS pass_back this is an AJAX call, just send back and die.
if (array_key_exists('pass_back',$_REQUEST)) {
    echo $_REQUEST["pass_back"];
    die();
}
//***********************************************

echo '<html><head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <script>
        function clickButton(currentId, nextId) {
            //alert(currentId+","+nextId); //check

            /*document.getElementById(currentId).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById(nextId).style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById(nextId).style.border = "5px solid red";//check*/

            //**************************
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
            else { xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","testing.php?pass_back=pass_back",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            //**************************

        }
    </script>
</head><body>';


//String of all the div's
$haystack = '<div id="div1" style="width:500px; height:250px; background-color:#fd77ba">Div1</div>
<div id="div2" style="width:500px; height:250px; background-color:#7781fd">Div2</div>
<div id="div3" style="width:500px; height:250px; background-color:#77fd9b">Div3</div>';

//Print all the divs
echo '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">';
echo $haystack;
echo '<button type="button" onClick="clickButton(1,2)" style="font-family:Oxygen,sans-serif; font-style: normal;font-variant: normal;font-weight: normal;font-size: 99%;line-height: normal;font-size-adjust: none;font-stretch: normal; background-color: #494f50; color: #ffffff; padding-top: 5px;padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 10px;margin-top: 50px;margin-right: 10px;margin-bottom: 50px;margin-left: 10px; text-decoration:none;">Submit</button>';
echo '</form>';
echo '</body></html>';
?>
```

Good luck.